# How to fetch data from the Tradingview graphs?

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am trying to fetch the graph data from one of the graphs at tradingview. Is this possible?

Using simple beautifulsoup does not give me raw data. Or at least I couldn't manage to.

Example Graph URL: https://www.tradingview.com/chart/I0H6E1GL/

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want to get is the data behind the graph, not really the graph if I am right. Then you don't need to fetch the graph to get the data, because all graphs are plotted based on data, not the other way round.

You cannot access financial data in tradingview yet as it explains on it's website:

> We don’t have an API that gives access to data as of now, but we are
> planning to add it in the future. Our REST API is meant for brokers
> who want to be supported on our trading platform.

But you can access financial data through other data providers who provide API, such as:

- Yahoo Finance API
- Alpha Vantage API
- Morningstar API

Some articles you can read:

[Top 9 Best Stock Market APIs (for Developers) [2021]](https://rapidapi.com/blog/best-stock-api/)

[Top Free Financial Data APIs](https://www.g2.com/categories/financial-data-apis/free)

Answer (score 0):

You can download the data behind the chart and any indicators on the page. On the top menu bar, to the left of the search magnifying glass icon is an inverted ^ to Manage Layouts via a dropdown menu. The fifth command down on that list is Export Chart Data. You can choose between UTC and UTC-4 time coding for your file. All the series on the chart will be downloaded. If you scroll the screen to the left, as in back in time, you can extend the data that will be downloaded. There is no API that I know of. I believe this functionality was added after the initial question was posted. This way is manual, cumbersome, slow and time consuming, but it works now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).